# How to change default query plugin for views?

Tags: views

By default Views uses 'views_plugin_query_default' plugin.
How can I alter something so that Views could use another class for building queries?

I found one good example how to write Views query plugins:
[building views query plugins](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-views-query-plugins)

But this example is for custom tables. But I need to have my own query builder for ordinary node, terms and users tables.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to have defined your query plugin to Views using `hook_views_plugins()`:

```
function MYMODULE_views_plugins() {
  return array(
    'query' => array(
      'myplugin' => array(
        'title' => 'My custom plugin',
        'handler' => 'MyCustomQueryClass',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then, you should be able to override the query class used for any of the built-in tables using `hook_views_data_alter()` and setting the `query class` key in the table base property:

```
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
    $data['node']['table']['base']['query class'] = 'myplugin';
}
```